# How to stop call / dialling number?

Tags: android, sdk

After dialling a number with the call intent within the activity, 
how do I make it delibrately stop after a period of time? then return to the main activity

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done (if it can then in my opinion it shouldn't be possible).

When you have a call in progress how can the phone 'know' how that call was initiated? A phone call is a phone call and there's no concept of ownership therefore it isn't legitimate to terminate it except when the user does so.

If it was possible there'd be all kinds of malware potentially interrupting calls to emergency services, important business calls etc etc

Comment: I used  PhoneStateListener to check for calls